# Rscript behaving badly

Tags: r

This works:

```
TMPDIR="/tmp/___"
export TMPDIR
mkdir -p "$TMPDIR"
script="$TMPDIR"/myscript
cat <<'EOF' > "$script"                                                                       
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla --slave                                                          
EOF                                                                                           

chmod 755 "$script"
ls -l "$script"
"$script"
ls -l "$script"
```

This removes `$script` and files in `/tmp` DO NOT RUN THIS IF YOU HAVE IMPORTANT STUFF IN `/tmp`:

```
TMPDIR="/tmp/   "
export TMPDIR
mkdir -p "$TMPDIR"
script="$TMPDIR"/myscript
cat <<'EOF' > "$script"                                                                       
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla --slave                                                          
EOF                                                                                           

chmod 755 "$script"
ls -l "$script"
"$script"
ls -l "$script"
```

The difference between these is only `$TMPDIR` contains spaces.

What is the reason for this difference in behaviour?

```
$ Rscript --version
R scripting front-end version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
$ cat /etc/issue.net 
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
```

It looks more and more like a bug. If you compile R from source and set TMPDIR=" ":

```
:
make[3]: Entering directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/profile'
building system startup profile
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/profile'
make[3]: Entering directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/translations'
building package 'translations'
make[4]: Entering directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/translations'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/translations'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/translations'
make[3]: Entering directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/base'
building package 'base'
make[4]: Entering directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/base'
/bin/bash: line 9:  /R3273656: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 12:  /R23273656: No such file or directory
cmp:  /R23273656: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ' /R23273656': No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [../../../share/make/basepkg.mk:65: mkRbase] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/base'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:31: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library/base'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:37: R] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/R-devel/src/library'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28: R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/R-devel/src'
make: *** [Makefile:62: R] Error 1
```

Also changing TMPDIR in sysutils.c:1893 to DUMMY makes the issue go away.

Comment: Can you please edit and give a bit of context? What OS is this on? Are you saying that running the script deletes all files in `/tmp` or some files? Only files? No directories? It looks like the only difference between the two cases is the value of `TMPDIR` and if it has trailing spaces, is that right or is there some other difference as well? It really helps if you point out the differences instead of making us try to find them since it is easy for us to miss something.

Comment: OK, this is just weird. I can indeed reproduce it on my Arch and it looks like it tries to delete everything in `/tmp`. What's worse, I get the exact same result if I simply run `touch "$TMPDIR"/myscript; Rscript "$TMPDIR"/myscript`. So giving `Rscript` an empty R script to run causes it to attempt to delete all files.

Comment: @terdon It is not the empty script. It is setting TMPDIR to a dir with spaces, that triggers the issue.

Comment: Yes, of course, I mean it is enough to just run `Rscript`, no need for the `Rscript` shebang line, just run `Rscript whateverFile` and we get the same issue. It really feels like a bug in `Rscript`.